# Interaction with qml objects from C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to interact with an **qml** object from **C++** file using **QtQuick**. But unfortunatelly unsuccessfully for now. Any idea what Im doing wrong? I tried 2 ways how to do it, result of the first was that *findChild()* returned *nullptr*, and in second try I am getting *Qml comnponent is not ready* error. What is the proper way to do it?

main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    // 1-st attempt how to do it - Nothing Found
    QObject *object = engine.rootObjects()[0];
    QObject *mrect = object->findChild<QObject*>("mrect");
    if (mrect)
        qDebug("found");
    else
        qDebug("Nothing found");
    //2-nd attempt - QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, "Page1Form.ui.qml");
    QObject *object2 = component.create();
    qDebug() << "Property value:" << QQmlProperty::read(object, "mwidth").toInt();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

        Page1 {
        }

        Page {
        }
    }
}
```

Page1.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Page1Form {
...
}
```

Page1.Form.ui.qml

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    property alias mrect: mrect
    property alias mwidth: mrect.width

    Rectangle
    {
        id: mrect
        x: 10
        y: 20
        height: 10
        width: 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findChild` takes object name as first parameter. But not ID.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild.

Here in your code, you are trying to query with id `mrect`. So it may not work.

Add `objectName` in your QML and then try accessing with `findChild` using object name.

Something like below (I did not try it. So chances of compile time errors):

Add objectName in QML

```
Rectangle
{
    id: mrect
    objectName: "mRectangle"
    x: 10
    y: 20
    height: 10
    width: 10
}
```

And then your findChild as shown below

```
QObject *mrect = object->findChild<QObject*>("mRectangle");
```